# Plotting Grouped Bar Chart with variables sharing the same time index (grouped bar chart) R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot some options data from Yahoo! finance - I'm sure this is super simple but I have simply hit a wall and have lost my patience.

This code downloads the options data for several maturities for a stock, cleans it up and assigns an index to it which is the maturity date for each option.

```
    #Options data
maturity_dates <- c("2021-07-16", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-30", "2021-08-06", 
                    "2021-08-13", "2021-08-20","2021-08-27", "2021-10-15",
                    "2022-01-21", "2023-01-20")
sndl_options <- getOptionChain("SNDL", Exp = maturity_dates)

#combine options data into a dataframe for puts and calls

#calls
options_df <- do.call("rbind", sndl_options[1:10])
calls_df <- rbind(options_df[1:10])
calls_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, calls_df)
calls_df$maturity <- substr(rownames(calls_df), start = 5, 10)
rownames(calls_df) <- 1:nrow(calls_df)
#fix maturity column and set as index
dates_vec <- 0
a <- 1
for(i in calls_df$maturity){
  if(i == "210716"){
    i <- "2021-07-16"
    dates_vec[a] <- i
    a <- a+1
  } else{
    if(i == "210723"){
      i <- "2021-07-23"
      dates_vec[a] <- i
      a <- a+1
    } else{
      if(i == "210730"){
        i <- "2021-07-30"
        dates_vec[a] <- i
        a <- a+1
      } else{
        if(i == "210806"){
          i <- "2021-08-06"
          dates_vec[a] <- i
          a <- a+1
        }else{
          if(i == '210813'){
            i <- "2021-07-30"
            dates_vec[a] <- i
            a <- a+1
          }else{
            if(i == "210820"){
              i <- "2021-08-20"
              dates_vec[a] <- i
              a <- a+1
            }else{
              if(i == "210827"){
                i <- "2021-08-27"
                dates_vec[a] <- i
                a <- a+1
              }else{
                if(i == '211015'){
                  i <- "2021-10-15"
                  dates_vec[a] <- i
                  a <- a+1
                }else{
                  if(i == '220121'){
                    i <- "2022-01-21"
                    dates_vec[a] <- i
                    a <- a+1
                  }else{
                    if(i == '230120'){
                      i <- "2023-01-20"
                      dates_vec[a] <- i
                      a <- a+1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
remove(i,a)
calls_df$maturity <- NULL; calls_df$LastTradeTime <- NULL
calls_df$ITM <- ifelse(calls_df$ITM == TRUE, 1, 0)
calls_df <- as.xts(calls_df, order.by = as.Date(dates_vec))
```

Now this should be OK with ggplot2 to create a grouped bar plot (a plot with bars sharing the same index, which in this case is : strike prices 1,...,K share the same index t. The y value here should be the Open Interest).

```
calls_plot <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(calls_df), aes(x = index(calls_df), y = OI, fill = Strike))
calls_plot + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

I am simply not getting the graph that I want. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the plot you are trying to achieve. First you could simplify your code considerably by getting rid of the bunch of `if` statements and simply use as `as.Date` for a proper date conversion. Additionally, at least for plotting it's not necessary to convert to an `xts` object.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

maturity_dates <- c("2021-07-16", "2021-07-23", "2021-07-30", "2021-08-06", 
                    "2021-08-13", "2021-08-20","2021-08-27", "2021-10-15",
                    "2022-01-21", "2023-01-20")
sndl_options <- getOptionChain("SNDL", Exp = maturity_dates)

calls_df <- lapply(sndl_options, `[[`, "calls")
calls_df <- bind_rows(calls_df, .id = "date")
calls_df$maturity <- substr(rownames(calls_df), start = 5, 10)
calls_df$maturity <- as.Date(calls_df$maturity, format = "%y%m%d")
calls_df$OI <- as.numeric(calls_df$OI)

ggplot(calls_df, aes(x = maturity, y = OI, fill = factor(Strike))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]